# Elasticsearch - "OR" query condition using match query and term query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following ***match*** query string:

```
curl -XGET 'my-es.com/my_indice/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "match" : {
          "state" : {
            "query" : ["ACTIVE", "INACTIVE"],
            "type" : "boolean"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}'
```

I guess it means `"state" = "ACTIVE" or "state" = "INACTIVE"`, but actually it performs `"state" = "INACTIVE"`.

Then I tried ***term*** query string:

```
curl -XGET 'my-es.com/my_indice/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
         "terms" : { "state" : ["ACTIVE", "INACTIVE"] }
      }]
    }
  }
}'
```

It performs `"state" = "ACTIVE" or "state" = "INACTIVE"`, showing ***term*** query supports multiple OR conditions via an array.

I'm curious about why ***match*** query does not support ***OR*** condition via an array? And it does not show any syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `match` query only supports a single string value to be specified. It is not explicitly specified in the [official `match` documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), but if you're willing to read some source code for [`MatchQueryParser.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/37d762914623c830714c942b95e11d728262b115/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/query/MatchQueryParser.java#L100), you can see that while parsing the `query` field, the parser will skip the tokens delimiting the start and end of the array and always override the `value` with the latest one being parsed, hence why you're seeing what you see, i.e. that `state` will be matched with `INACTIVE` only.

What you can do, however, is to put both tokens inside the same string like below, and both tokens will be taken into account:

```
curl -XGET 'my-es.com/my_indice/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "match" : {
          "state" : {
            "query" : "ACTIVE INACTIVE",
            "type" : "boolean"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Great answer! While if my query condition is `"name" = "nike inc" or "name" = "samsung inc"`, then what the query will be like? I think `"query" : "ACTIVE INACTIVE"` only handles single word case.